# Why the Xcode UI is blurred?

Tags: xcode

I installed xcode on my mac, the path is /Application/Xcode.app. When I open it, the UI is kinda blurred, as shown below.
[blurred UI when the path is /Application/Xcode.app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdo3f.png)

However, when I renamed the app as Xcode12.app or any other name, the UI becomes normal and clear. As shown below
[normal UI when the path is /Application/Xcode12.app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWrau.png)

I have tried totally uninstalling Xcode and reinstall it. However, the same issue exists. I have tried different versions, like 12.1, 12.3, 12.... and they are all the same.

Any guys know how to solve it?? Thanks!!!

Comment: Any solution for that yet? The first Xcode popup is fine for me but instead the simulator name in the top center is blurry, while e.g. "Build Succeeded" in the same bar is fine. I'm using Xcode 13.0 currently but this has been a problem since at least 12.4! I put a different app in the same spot but everything's normal there, so it's definitely not my screen but an Xcode problem.